# Why do my integer array elements contain the wrong values when I assign it character values in C and how can I fix this?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, character

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *string = "abcd";
    int i;int j;
    int array[5];
    for(i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
       array[i] = string[i];  
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
      printf("array[i] %d\n",array[i]);


     array[0] = string[0]; 
     printf("array[0] %d\n",array[0]);


return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
array[i] 4195888
array[i] 4195888
array[i] 4195888
array[i] 4195888
array[0] 97
```

I thought the output would be:

```
array[i] 97
array[i] 98
array[i] 99
array[i] 100
array[0] 97
```

If this assignment:

```
array[0] = string[0];
```

assigns 97 to array[0], then why doing similar assignments within the loop, produces a different output, and how can I fix my code so that the output would look as I expected it to be?

Comment: In this loop, you should iterate over variable i, not over variable j:

    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        printf("array[%d]\n", j, array[j]);

Comment: @LPs nitpick: change i to j in the format string also. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, I deleted. Other answers/comments are better. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is mismatched index values.

```
for(j=0; j<4; j++)
      printf("array[i] %d\n",array[i]);
```

should be

```
for(j=0; j<4; j++)                       // j is the loop control variable
      printf("array[j] %d\n",array[j]);  // so, use j as index here
```

Otherwise, what happens is you use the last value of `i` as index, which here, is an attempt to access uninitialized element (i.e., `array[4]`) which contains *indeterminate* value. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To be on safe side, you better initialize the local variables to your function.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, your printf loop is on j but you are using i  as the index into the array, whereas you should index using j. You also have j hardcoded within the printf, and it should be %d and then filled in with j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *string = "abcd";
    int i;int j;
    int array[5];
    for(i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
       array[i] = string[i];  
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
      printf("array[%d] %d\n",j,array[j]);


     array[0] = string[0]; 
     printf("array[0] %d\n",array[0]);


return 0;
}
```

Then your output will be as expected:

```
array[0] 97
array[1] 98
array[2] 99
array[3] 100
array[0] 97
```